# Version control with git 1.7.1 in pycharm?

Tags: git, pycharm

I have just downloaded pycharm, and wanted to integrate version control in it, as my current python project is already on a git repository.

The thing is, my git version is 1.7.1, and when trying to configure version control, pycharm issues the following message:

```
            Git version
            The configured version of Git is not supported: 1.7.1.0.
            The minimal supported version is 1.7.1.1. Please update.
```

Yet right-clicking on source files yields a git sub-menu, and I can access logs, commit files, do comparisons between branches...

On the other hand, the pycharm help states, among prerequisites to working with git:

> It is strongly recommended that you use version 1.7.1.1 or higher.

**Does anyone know if there is any real hazard using version 1.7.1?**

**Sidenote:** I do not wish to update git for now, as my peers working on the project are all using this version (and although git seems to be backwards compatible to a great extent, I do not wish to tempt the devil), and I would need to ask someone with admin rights to do it for me.

**[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071965/unsupported-git-version)** (but does not answer the full scope of my question, since the OP's solution is to update git).

Comment: Hazards?  Besides the fact that it's unsupported and the functionality that PyCharm is likely built and depends on 1.7.1.1, there's likely no hazard.

Comment: @Makoto Hazards as in "must I expect weird behavior from basic git features, or can I assume safely that everything will work smoothly?"

Comment: I mean...the IDE has already told you that it isn't supported, but you know this.  Anything you do with unsupported systems is presumed you taking the risk into your own hands.

Comment: Have you asked Jetbrains why they added that minimum version requirement?  They may be better able to answer the question since they wrote the software.

Comment: @PatrickSteele I have posted on Jetbrains forum, with little luck thus far, so I came poking on SO to see if anyone has had any experience with PyCharm and an unsupported git version.

Comment: I'm mostly curious, since you already stated that an update is not okay: Is 1.7.1 a typo (and you meant your old version is 2.7.1) or are you and your peers reluctant to update a 7 year old piece of (fast moving) software? http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tag/?h=v1.7.1

Comment: Release notes for the ancient 1.7.1.1 are here - potentially there's one thing that PyCharm expects? http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.1.1.txt - there are several '1.7.1 is doing something terrible/suboptimal/wrong' points in that very document that would scare me more than the PyCharm warning itself.

Comment: @BenjaminPodszun Indeed, there is no typo, we are running on 1.7.1. I know this is seriously outdated, but updating it means updating it on all our machines and I would need to convince my boss and the sysadmin team. At the light of those release notes though, I will definitely talk to them and try to get it done, thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a detailed answer from the Jetbrains forums:

> 1.7.1.1 is the first git version that supports GIT_ASKPASS variable. IDE uses this to handle authentication prompts that git throws when
>   accessing remotes.
>
> Given the above, with git 1.7.1 you probably will not be able to
>   access remotes that prompt for password (mostly HTTP). The workaround
>   for this would be to pull/push to such remotes from the command line.
>   In a case of SSH access, it should work fine.Other git operations
>   should work.
>
> Other git operations should work.

Source: Dmitriy Smirnov, Jetbrains staff.